What should I do to get rid of leaf and flower eating budworm/caterpillar on my petunia?
I stay in tropical weather and I planted a petunia plant 20 days back,
but from day 7 I saw holes in my leaves and just a few days back I saw a small caterpillar like stuff  that's eating my leaf. I got rid of it immediately.
After talking to a local nursery recommendation  I sprayed a kaka bio stimulant (its composition Natural lactones: 0.4%
Natural alkaloids: 0.2%
Aqueous media: 99.4%). Which is an organic insecticide but after 2 days nothing has changed and the flowers and buds are still getting eaten.


The solution you sprayed was 99.4% water, containing minute amounts of the two other ingredients. Sprayed insecticides such as this product as well as neem oil or insecticidal soap kill insects only on contact with them, so spraying the plant and not the insects will generally do no good.
The first ingredient of the "stimulant" - lactones - may have some insecticidal properties, depending upon whether those lactones are avermectins or milbemycins, as most lactones do not have those properties. Without further information about the exact lactones in the product, I cannot say whether your solution was useful or just "snake oil". Note that avermectin-based insecticides are not for use on food crops (US EPA) and are usually applied as poisoned bait, although foliar sprays are permitted.
Note also that the Food Ministry of Japan has discovered that avermectin can harm mammals in high quantities, so be careful with them.
Alkaloids may or may not be poisonous, so again, without knowing WHICH alkaloids are in the solution it cannot be determined whether those in the solution are useful or not.
I would switch to an actual insecticide, preferably one that uses bait. Do not switch to a systemic insecticide, since those kill more beneficial insects than problem insects on flowering plants.
